# ReadyState substitute for IE11 in VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, internet-explorer-11

Please, I've just bought a new pc that came with IE 11.

I have a lot of codes in VBA using the

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
```

But it seems that microsoft removed this feature as it says in its [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They say that the Replacement feature are script.onload, but I am not sure how to use it in VBA.

Can anyone help me?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`readystate` is only removed for `script` elements...

Comment: I am trying to run the code on IE11, but it keeps looping in the ReadyState even when the page is already loaded. When I run the code in the IE10 it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: If you debug the code does `ReadyState` have a value?

Comment: `READYSTATE_COMPLETE=4` I've also tried `While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend`, but it didnt work either. I am running the code on my old pc (IE10, Windows 8), because i got to get this done... So don't worry... Thank you anyway for the help!

Comment: hi, i'm also stuck on this method. is there any suggestion? readystate value is 3.